# three.js transparent png texture strange border webgl

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am having a strange problem when using pngs as a texture in three.js. The pngs get strange borders at the area between visible and transparent. I allready tried to play around with alphatest value but then sometimes the image disapears completly in areas where are really thin 1px lines. Is there a solution how to solve this?

```
var explosionTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'explosion.png' );
        boomer = new TextureAnimator( explosionTexture, 4, 4, 16, 55 ); // texture, #horiz, #vert, #total, duration.
        var explosionMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: explosionTexture } );
        explosionMaterial.transparent = true;
        var cube2Geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 64, 64, 1, 1 );
        cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( cube2Geometry, explosionMaterial );
        cube2.position.set(100,26,0);
        scene.add(cube2);


        // renderer

        //renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false, premultipliedAlpha: true  } );
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
```

Comment: some code will be great

Comment: Here you can see how the 1px thin line looks in the editor:
[1]: http://i.imgur.com/Www2PsR.png?1?2013

and here how it looks like in the browser as a texture:
[2]: http://i.imgur.com/Z3J9S0f.png?1?5201

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i solved it like this:

```
            var c2GVertices = cube2Geometry.vertices;


            for (var i = 0; i < c2GVertices.length; i++) {
              c2GVertices[i].x =  c2GVertices[i].x - 0.5;
              c2GVertices[i].y =  c2GVertices[i].y - 0.5;
            }
```

is there an easier way to move all vertices a half pixel?

Answer (score 13):

Just try this:

```
explosionTexture.anisotropy = 0;
explosionTexture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
explosionTexture.minFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
```

Also you should not use antialaising when constructing the renderer:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
```

Did this to preview minecraft texture packs, works great :-)

Comment: Thx, it helped me .

Comment: Thanks, very helpful advice.

With Three.js r101, I was missing `material.transparent = true` to avoid ugly white pixels artifacts near the borders of my image having alpha transparency (already present in original question).

Any reason why antialiasing should not be used?

Comment: @FrostyZ I specifically used it to preview texture packs for the minecraft game and having anti aliasing enabled made the textures too washy.

Answer (score 5):

Use material blending, the following configuration worked for me:

```
material.blending = THREE.CustomBlending
material.blendSrc = THREE.OneFactor
material.blendDst = THREE.OneMinusSrcAlphaFactor
```

See this example:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_blending_custom

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations, you've run directly into the Texel-to-Pixel-mapping-trap. :)

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should help you out of there, although it's not WebGL the basics still apply.

Comment: Oh no :). are you sure? But the border is not coloured like my image its more like gray. Shouldn't it be coloured like the image when i am in the texel to picel trap? I will try you solution anyways...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tried all the solutions on this page. They all failed.

What worked for me was to use the correct `Texture.wrapS` (horizontal wrapping) and `Texture.wrapT` (vertical wrapping) for the sprite texture.

I personally was finding this ugly edge on the top of my sprite. I just had to make sure my `Texture.wrapT` setting was `THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping` instead of `THREE.RepeatWrapping`.

Solved the issue perfectly without messing with alpha test values, texture filters, vertices or antialiasing.